# Simple Injector:Getting an instance in an extension method

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

I have an extension method where I want to be able to get an instance of a class via the container
e.g.

```
public static string EncryptString(this SecureString input)
{
    if (input == null) return null;

    var encryptor = Injector.Container.GetInstance<ICryptFactory>().GetEncryptor(salt);

    return encryptor.Encrypt(input.ToInsecureString());
}
```

However, I don't really want the dependency on the container but I can't work out how else to get an instance.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: why don't just pass the instance as an argument?

Comment: you are right. Sometimes the obvious is too obvious to see.

Comment: There's a security flaw in your code. The `salt` seems to be some static constant and this is a security problem. 1. Passwords should be hashed, not encrypted. 2. Each hash should get its own salt; using the same salt for each password allows attackers to see which users have the same password. For more information on the subject, please [read this](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).

Comment: @Steven - you are right. However, this isn't used to encrypt user passwords with a hashing function but values in config files via X509 certificates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you want to use constructor injection to inject the dependencies a class needs. An extension method however, is just a static method on a static class and you can't do constructor injection on static classes.

Because of this you are currently falling back to the [Service Locator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern), which is [far from ideal](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) and should be avoided whenever possible.

So you will either have to promote your class to a non-static class and your extension method to a non-static method to allow it to be injected as usual, or you will have to pass in the encryptor into the method.

Comment: I think adding a parameter is the simplest in this case. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just inject an `IPasswordHasher` abstaction into your consumers that contain `string CreateHash(string pwd)` and `bool Compare(string password, string hash)` method? You can inject the `ICryptFactory` in the `IPasswordHasher` implmenentation instead of injecting it into a consumer.

Comment: The use case is actually in a config file via a custom ConfigurationSection. Is there a recommended way of creating these via dependency injection? Maybe this is a whole 'nother question

Comment: That would probably be a new question, but in general I try to prevent the application from reading from the configuration file, except the composition root; the part where you wire your dependencies.